# select() selects more columns than I tell it to. Why? - R

Tags: r, select, dplyr, data-manipulation

For example, when I use `select()` from `dplyr`:

```
mtcars %>% select(., cyl, disp)
```

It selects correctly `cyl` and `disp`. But when I do it in the dataframe I'm working on, (let's assume it's `iris`):

```
iris %>% select(., Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
```

it selects `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, and `Petal.Length` even when I'm not telling to select `Petal.Length`. It's very frustrating, as I cannot find in documentation, stackoverflow or in google any explanation.

At the end, I'm wondering when `select()` would pick columns I'm not telling it to pick? Any suggestions?

**EDIT - DATA:**

```
structure(list(codigo_estacion = 11545000L, institucion = "DGA", 
    fuente = "dga_web", nombre = "Rio Baker Bajo Ã‘Adis", altura = 45L, 
    latitud = -47.5, longitud = -72.9749984741211, codigo_cuenca = 115L, 
    nombre_sub_cuenca = "Rio Baker Entre Arriba Rio De La Colonia Y Desemb.", 
    cantidad_observaciones = 4736L, fecha = structure(15624, class = "Date"), 
    caudal = 692, gauge_id = 11545000L, gauge_name = "Rio Baker Bajo Ã‘Adis", 
    precip_promedio = 0.454545468091965, temp_max_promedio = 17.0166664123535, 
    estacion_ano = "Primavera", caudal_extremo = 0, temp_extremo = 0, 
    precip_extremo = 0), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
    codigo_estacion = 11545000L, estacion_ano = "Primavera", 
    .rows = list(1L)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

The code I'm using:

```
df %>% dplyr::select(codigo_estacion, caudal_extremo)
```

But it's giving columns `estacion_ano`, `codigo_estacion` and `caudal_extremo`.

Comment: It works as it should for me. Restart R and try again

Comment: Don't know if it's related but the `.` should be unnecessary in those calls, the dataframe is passed *implicitly* to the function when you use `%>%`.

Comment: @prosoitos I did, and still not working.

Comment: @Marius: that is totally true, but having the unnecessary `.` does not affect the result

Comment: @Marius I use it just for the sake of readability, but I already tried not using the dot and still is giving the same result.

Comment: @Chris: the code works fine with `iris`. So maybe you should provide your data. Otherwise, I don't see how we can help you

Comment: Did you execute a `group_by` in the iris dataset? When you execute a group_by, the grouping columns are automatically added to the output, even if you do not select them. Run `class(iris)` and check if the output contains `grouped_df`.

Comment: @RenatoDinhani you are right. the result of class(df) is: [1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame". As it's still grouped (but I already used it for mutate() and summarise()), how can I ungroup it? Or each time I use group_by do I need to ungroup in order to keep using the dataframe?

Comment: The data frame will remain grouped until you ungroup it. You can ungroup at any time with the `ungroup` function: `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(n=n()) %>% ungroup`.

Comment: When you run `select` on a grouped data frame (say, like this: `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% select(mpg)`) do you get a message like this: `Adding missing grouping variables: \`cyl\``

Comment: Are you using Jupyter Notebook or Juypyter Lab?   I use frequently use the iRkernel in Jupyter Lab and find that sometimes I do not get the result I expect from the code within a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you provided is a data frame grouped by the variable `estacion_ano`. When using `select` on a grouped data frame, grouping variables will automatically be added to the result. You may want to `ungroup` just before using `select`:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::select(codigo_estacion, caudal_extremo)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
# codigo_estacion caudal_extremo
#           <int>          <dbl>
# 1      11545000              0
```