# How do I find the line number where dplyr is telling me a missing group has been added?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have an 892 line function which seems to be working well, except I am getting the message

```
 Adding missing grouping variables: `schoolType`
```

I have been unable to locate the line that is triggering this message. I thought I had used `ungroup` in every situation that needed it, it turns out I am wrong.

Because it is a message from `dplyr` and not a warning or error, I don't get a traceback option or similar. I would prefer not to suppress the message as something in my code is possibly not working quite as intended.

Rather than suppressing the message, what can I do to find out the line number that is triggering it? I'm only getting the message once, so I assume it is only a problem on one line.

I searched to see if anyone else had the problem, and their questions were unrelated to working out the line number that is causing the message.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: the linked question is not a duplicate. The other question is **not** about finding the row number where the message is originating. That is my question.

Second edit: the select was the problem part of the code. Which, if I had known the line number... (see here [select() selects more columns than I tell it to. Why? - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58424058/select-selects-more-columns-than-i-tell-it-to-why-r)) although that question doesn't seem to mention the message.

Comment: While the _symptom_ is a duplicate, the _question_ of how to get the line-number generating the message is different. I've reopened.

Comment: Not a direct answer but another tactic you could employ would be to add logging lines like "message("Step 15: line 800")" to help narrow down where in the script the message is generated.

Comment: “ I have an 892 line function”. That’s the root of the problem. Break the overall problem into smaller pieces. Check each in turn. Isolate the issue, then fix it.

Comment: After ripping my hair out some more, I finally found the problem. The variable was being added to my output because I hadn't included it in a select after I took a sample. I had to ungroup before I used select. Does anyone know if this behaviour is intended?

Comment: If I had known the line number, it would have showed me that the select was causing the problem, not the group-by() - which I couldn't work out how I messed it up. Answer - I hadn't.

Answer (score 0):

When you `group_by` variables and then `select(.)` one or more columns that do not include that variable, it'll keep it for you.

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  select(disp)
# Adding missing grouping variables: `cyl`
# # A tibble: 32 × 2
# # Groups:   cyl [3]
#      cyl  disp
#    <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     6  160 
#  2     6  160 
#  3     4  108 
#  4     6  258 
#  5     8  360 
#  6     6  225 
#  7     8  360 
#  8     4  147.
#  9     4  141.
# 10     6  168.
# # ℹ 22 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Find where you started `group_by(.)` and then find the next `select(.)` before the paired `ungroup()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. And no, the linked question did NOT answer my question.

Comment: To be fair @Michelle, your question has no sample data, no code, no demonstration of how the message is triggered in your case. Given what we have here, I don't disagree with closing it as "duplicate" or closing it as "needs details". ... But I also realize that I did not resolve your question, which is how to know which code line number. I have no idea if that's easy or even possible, since the `%>%` pipes tend to make things perhaps harder to figure things out.

Comment: I have 892 lines of code. I can't post the entire function. All I want to know is if I can add something to the function that will output the line number.

Comment: If the answer is no, there is nothing I can add that will print out the line number then that's fine. I'll need to comment out multiple blocks of code to find it. I just thought there might be an easier way.

Comment: While I understand that sharing 800+ lines of code is not ideal, I don't understand the complexity of code such that you cannot find `group_by` and the subsequent `select`. Sorry, no gem today.

Comment: The answer is no, it can't be done? I asked because the code is long and complicated. All I wanted to know is if it was possible and, if so, what code to insert into the function. What you've suggested, and I have done, is go through the code blocks manually. Which is the method to use if no, there is no code to I can use to locate the line number.

Comment: As I said, I have no idea if that's easy or even possible.